# Align image img with text in box

Tags: php, html, css, image, alignment

***EDIT:*** This works now thanks to ' olly_uk '

***EDIT2:*** It works now, but the alignment of the boxes is wrong. You can view a screenshot [HERE](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/1614/crapy.jpg). Without any text it will align perfectly with 2 boxes on each line at a perfect distance from each other, but with text it echo's it under each other. Why?

I am trying to echo a image, then in that image I want to echo text from a database.
Well it echo's the images (3, because I only have 3 product examples in the database), but the products are not aligned in the boxes. It comes under it. I have searched on google but could not find anything

Is it even possible to use e.g. margin-top to move the posted echo so I could align it in the box?

I want to use style or class in the PHP...

Example image: [IMAGE](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/6903/errorxii.jpg)

adding `<style>p{...};h3{...};</style>` worked

Code sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>BOX</title>
<link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<style>
    p {
    position:relative;
    top:-240px;
    left:180px;
    }
    h3 {
    position:relative;
    top:-270px;
    left:30px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<?php
    include 'includes/connection.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<body>

<div class="header navpos c1" id="nav">
            <table summary="header" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="home"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="about"><a href="about.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="twitter"><a href="index.html"><img src="includes/images/f_logo.png" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="facebook"><a href="index.html"><img src="includes/images/t_logo.png" alt="link to Syndicate Plus Twitter" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>

<div class="offers">
    <div class="content_box">
        <?php
            while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<img src="includes/images/content_box.png" border=0 />';
                echo "<h3>" . $products['products'] . "</h3>";
                echo "<p>" . $products['description'] . "</p>";
            }   
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to display the images next to each other?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, other than you're using PHP to generate some html. This is an html layout question, and I have no idea what exactly you're trying to accomplish. What is an `<hp>` tag?

Comment: I edited the <hp> tag, it should have been  <p> tag. I uploaded an example image, link in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you could achieve this using CSS. by having a negative top to bump the text over the top of the image.  will try to give some example code when i get home.

check this out in the mean time, [w3schools CSS-positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

hope that helped

EDIT: added code to show what i mean

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>text over image</title>
    <style>

        p {
        position:relative;
        top:-200px;
        }
        h2 {
        position:relative;
        top:-140px;
        }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <img src="/images/office1.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
    <h2>test text</h2>
    <p>test desciption text</p>
    <hr/>
    <img src="/images/office1.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
    <h2>test text</h2>
    <p>test desciption text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. The <style>p {...} and h3 {...}</style> interacted with "<h3>"and"<p>".. This looks so obvious. Thank you! I would give you a useful point but I'm not allowed.

Comment: Hey again, can you help me out again? The boxes are not aligned good...  You can see a screenshot, posted in the question.. Thanks